# UISearchbar Hide/Show Issue in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have `UISearchBar` on my `UITableView` set as its `tableViewHeader` using InterfaceBuilder. I have hidden it under the `UINavigationBar` using

`self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0.0, self.searchBar.frame.size.height);`

in my `ViewWillAppear` method. The problem is that if I go to the detailView and come back to this `TableView`, if the `TableView` has more than the screen visible cells, it works fine and hides the `SearchBar` as it is suppose to do, but if there are less than screen visible cells (i.e. tableview has 0 - 4 cells) then the `SearchBar` **doesn't Hide**.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

thanks in advance

Comment: Actually Can you explain what you want.

Comment: Hide `UISearchbar` until the user swipes the `tableView` down to use it.. it hides properly when the array has more data  than the visible content of `UITableView` but doesn't hide when there is no or less than visible content data.